How do I 'inflate' the radius of the curve instead of trimming?

This is my curve. I'm trying to achieve a snake like object moving along it. I'm currently using the trim curve along with a float curve as a factor for the radius.
However I want to put distribute instances on the inflated parts that appear and disappear with the size of the radius. As I currently have it set up they follow along with the object. I want them to be static and only enlarge with the enlarged part of the curve.
Is there a way of animating which part of the curve the float curve factor is effecting?
Ultimately I wanted to make a disney style sparkle path (like someone's waving a magic wand).
Here's my node set up:


It takes next to no effort to convert your setup the way you want: in your case trimming the curve offsets the length - reduces it by the trimmed Start value. So do the same without trimming and you don't have to worry about points moving, because the curve isn't changed at all:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror
I deliberately positioned the icospheres very densely to show the shapes match, but you probably want to set the resampling Length to $0.135 × 2 = 0.27$ based on the maximum radius specified in the Float Curve:

Imgur mirror
